# LINQ to SQL and adding multiple records to foreign table for a single primary key

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I have a database with around 20 tables, and one of them is an "attachment" table. All but one table has a foreign key to the "Identifier" table so that each record in the Identifier table identifies one record in all of the other tables.

For the attachments table, I have my two primary keys which identify the record from the Identifiers table that it is associated with. I have two other fields, one of which is supposed to act as an "index" to indicate that there can be multiple attachments per Identifier.

The issue I'm running into is that I cannot figure out how to add multiple attachments to a single Identifier object using LINQ to SQL. I know I cannot have multiple records with the same primary keys, so would I have to make the attachment index a primary key as well? Would that turn the Attachment member of the Identifier object in my C# project into a list? I guess I'm not understanding how I can have multiple records in the Attachment table refer to the same Identifier record.

Comment: You would need a new primary key which is attachment number where each attachment would have a unique id.  The id can simply be an incremental number.  Every time you add new item you first check database for largest id number an make new id one larger.

Comment: The indexing is already handled by the application, but would doing this, adding a new primary key, give me a LIST of attachments in the Identifier class in my C# project? I guess I'm just wondering how I would be able to add those multiple records to the same Identifier object in C# / LINQ.

Comment: A database is a flat object with rows and columns like a spreadsheet.  Tables are views of the database that contain a subset of columns of the database  So when you read/write a table you are accessing a portion of the database.  Your attachments are a row of the database.  Adding an attachment can either over-write an existing row or creating a new row.  If you have only one primary key then each row of the database would have a different primary key.  In the case where you have multiple primary keys an object (one primary key) would be on multiple rows of the database.

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me not long after I posted this. It works now, but I need to figure out a better way of writing changes to the attachments for a particular Identifier, because right now it just clears all existing records and rewrites them according to the current attachments. There usually aren't more than one or two attachments, though, so it isn't that costly.

Comment: If it is clearing all old items then you aren't using two keys, only one.

Comment: When I store a record, I clear the list of Attachment objects in the Identifier object and then insert all the attachments from scratch. This will overwrite the Attachment records that exist for the given primary keys. So it has to delete and re-insert every Attachment, even if no change was made. THAT is the problem I'm talking about.

Also, I originally had two primary keys. With the index now being a primary key, I have 3.

Comment: Normally with SQL database I Insert updates.  The response to the insert command is an integer indicating the number of row affected.  If the return number is zero then the row already exists so then I do an Update to change the existing row.  In your case it is more complicated with two primary keys.  You would need to keep in c# the attachment number.  Not sure how you can track the attachment number in c#.

Comment: The problem is that "updates" are done by modifying objects returned by a LINQ query (LINQ to SQL generates classes to represent your tables), and you modify those class members and call "submitChanges" on your database object to send any changes to the database. It automatically handles updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the indexing column in the Attachments table to be a primary key and refreshing the DBML schema in Visual Studio, the EntityRef object referring to the Attachment entity in the Identifier class changes to an EntitySet, allowing me to add multiple Attachment entities to each Identifier.